# how to identify an instance of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I will usually have a number of instances of Visual studio 2005 open on the same machine loaded with different versions of the same solution.
I would like very much to be able to do is to identify which instance is which (prefferably from the taskbar or the title bar) without having to drill down to an individual file and right click view properties to see the path of the file. I do a workaround to change the background colour of the text editor of each instance but this only lasts as long as the instance is alive and its a pain.
The other issue is similar so when I open Studio I have n instances of a solution with the same name and no way at all to identify which one is which.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Typo Should read : 
The other issue is similar so when I open Studio I have n instances of a solution in the Recent Projects list with the same name and no way at all to identify which one is which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it: [How To Show Full File Path (or Anything Else) in VS 2005 Title Bar](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/32):

> I saw an interesting request on
>   discussion forums today. A user wants
>   to show the full path of currently
>   edited file in the IDE main window
>   caption. This used to be case in VS
>   .NET 2003 but VS 2005 shows only
>   solution name.

Comment: Thats fantastic, well done. And an excellent link too.
Thanks